# Animation of a single photo by joining multiple pieces

Tags: beamer, animations

I want to animation in beamer of a single which I divided into 900 equal pieces. I named them image_part_001 to image_part_900. Now I want to do animation by joining them one by one to make the full photo in the final frame. I have tried the following but I got one by one separately. My requirement is to join them side by side to make the full photo at the end.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\textsc{\bf Knowledge g{\Large r}{\LARGE o}{\huge w}{\Huge S} When Shared}
\animategraphics[loop,autoplay,width=0.1\linewidth]{30}{image_part_}{001}{900}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a late answer, may be to late for you, but nevertheless:

The `animate` package doesn't support assembling a picture piece by piece. So instead this code includes the complete picture, covers it and then uncovers it from left to right and top to bottom.

Unfortunately, `animate` seems to clip the animation, which may lead to a thin visible border, depending on the resulution and the viewer. A way around that would be to draw a thin border on the picture in the color the picture should be covered with.

The parameters for the new `\animatepicture` command are described in the code. If you want to uncover just from top to bottom, set x-slices (`#3`) to 1. And for uncovering from left to right, set y-slices (`#4`) to 1.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{animate}

\makeatletter
\newsavebox\imagebox
\newcount\@animate@frames
\newcount\@animate@start
% parameters
% #1 optional arguments for animateline
% #2 frame rate
% #3 x-slices
% #4 y-slices
% #5 optional arguments for \includegraphics
% #6 picture file
% #7 cover color, default: white
\NewDocumentCommand{\animatepicture}{O{}mmmO{}mO{white}}{%
    \sbox{\imagebox}{\includegraphics[#5]{#6}}%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\usebox{\imagebox}}%
    \pgfmathsetcount{\@animate@start}{#3*#4}%
    \pgfmathsetcount{\@animate@frames}{\@animate@start+1}%
    \begin{animateinline}[#1]{#2}
        \multiframe{\@animate@frames}{iuc=\@animate@start+-1}{
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (\wd\imagebox,\ht\imagebox);
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\xparts}{#3-mod(\iuc,#3)}
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\yparts}{floor(\iuc/#3)}
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\xstep}{\wd\imagebox/#3}
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\ystep}{\ht\imagebox/#4}
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\xe}{\wd\imagebox}
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\xm}{ifthenelse(\xparts==0,\xe,\xparts*\xstep)}
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\xs}{ifthenelse(\yparts==0,\xm,0)}
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\ys}{0}
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\ym}{\yparts*\ystep}
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\ye}{ifthenelse(\xparts==#3,\ym,\ym+\ystep)}
                \filldraw[#7,fill=#7,very thick]
                    (\xs pt,\ys pt) -- (\xe pt,\ys pt) -- (\xe pt,\ye pt) --
                    (\xm pt,\ye pt) -- (\xm pt,\ym pt) -- (\xs pt,\ym pt) -- cycle;
            \end{tikzpicture}
        }
    \end{animateinline}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\textsc{\bf Knowledge g{\Large r}{\LARGE o}{\huge w}{\Huge S} When Shared}

\animatepicture[loop,autoplay]{30}{30}{30}[scale=0.75]{example-image.pdf}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution could be to include the images in a loop. To make sure that the line breaks are at the correct position, the available text width (the size of the minipage in the following example), needs to be n times the width of the individual images.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{xmpmulti}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{center}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}%
    \foreach \x in {1,...,9} {%
        \includegraphics<+->[width=.3333\textwidth]{test-\x}\hspace{0pt}%
    }%
\end{minipage}%
\end{center}%
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```